# Who was the youngest player to play in an NHL game?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, records, nhl, stanley-cup

I would like to know who was the youngest player to play in an NHL game. It would be also interesting to know also some related records (youngest goalscorer, youngest player with an assists, similar records for Stanley Cup) and Top 10 of this statistic (if it is available somewhere).

I have checked [List of NHL records (individual)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NHL_records_%28individual%29) at Wikipedia (here is [link to the current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_NHL_records_%28individual%29&oldid=642858689)), but the only things mentioning age I found there were were that the youngest player in NHL history to win the Calder Memorial Trophy was Nathan Mackinnon and the youngest goaltender to win 300, 400, 500, 600 regular-season games was Martin Brodeur.

Comment: List of youngest goalscorers as of May 2013 can be found in this article: [Monahan joins Barkov among youngest scorers](http://www.nhl.com/ice/news.htm?id=685392).

Comment: I also found this, which is on the opposite side of the spectrum: [List of oldest National Hockey League players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_National_Hockey_League_players) - Wikipedia.

Comment: Interestingly I think Hasek was the youngest to join a professional league at the age of 16, according to wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominik_Ha%C5%A1ek but it was not the NHL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Guinness World Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/youngest-player-to-play-in-nhl), [Armand "Bep" Guidolin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bep_Guidolin) was the youngest player to ever play in an NHL game:

> At 16 years 11 months, Armand "Bep" Guidolin (Canada, b. 9 December 1925) became the youngest player to skate in an NHL game playing for the Boston Bruins (USA) in a 3-1 loss to the Toronto Maple Leafs (Canada) on 12 November 1942.